# NameError: name 'x' is not defined when running Pipline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently reading the "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow". I get an error when I am trying to recreate the Transformation Pipelines code. How can I fix this? Here is the original data: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb
line 73

**Code**

```
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    
    num_pipeline = Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = "median")),
                            ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
                            ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
                            ])
    
    housing_num_tr = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num)
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-158-bc2e64db52f3> in <module>
          8                         ])
          9 
    ---> 10 housing_num_tr = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num)
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
        376         """
        377         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
    --> 378         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
        379 
        380         last_step = self._final_estimator
    
   
    
    NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: I don't know about that error, but `housing_num` is not defined in your code...

Comment: Are you sure that traceback is correct?  The highlighted line does not use `x` at all.

Comment: Please provide toy data, so we can reproduce the error :)

Comment: I have defined `housing_num`. I followed the exact same code in the book but it gives me errors. here is the link of code (https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb), line 73.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question, but I've come to a similar error.

The problem was that I typed something wrong in the CombinedAttributesAdder class implementation. I simply copied again from the book and then it worked!